# how to pull a managed VisualForce component onto my Visual Force Page

Tags: managed-package, visualforce-component

I am replacing a managed custom VisualForce page that is step 3 of a wizard.

On the custom VisualForce page I created to replace the original, I am able to pull in the wizard component, so, the steps show up at the top properly, but, I am unable to figure out how to pull in the main component that was on the page being replaced.  My page needs that component to be in it, below my customizations.

but, when I try it, I get an error when saving that says:
Unknown property:StandardController.theOptions, note, also, in the error, it doesn't say .StandardController, just StandardController with no . in between, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.  Sorry in advance if my etiquette is a bit off, I am a newbie. I don't want to put in the name of the actual custom object, because that is from a managed package, but, the object in question is the standard controller for the page, I am also wondering, if it is related to the extension to the controller, which is managed, and, I can't see the code, but, maybe I should be defining my own instead of trying to use that one.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: If the component's controller isn't global, I doubt you'll be able to use it, since you can't hook into code that's merely "public."